# Answer to a specific question and a very broad question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, answers, on-topic-definition

I was composing an answer to [Can I distribute a GPL executable (not a library) in a closed-source application?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/289785/can-i-distribute-a-gpl-executable-not-a-library-in-a-closed-source-application#) when I discovered it has been closed as a duplicate of [Can I use GPL, LGPL, MPL licensed packages with my application and make it closed source?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125606/can-i-use-gpl-lgpl-mpl-licensed-packages-with-my-application-and-make-it-close#comment599873_289924) .

Since my answer 1)covers the original matter much more substantially than any answer in either question, and 2)couldn't be adapted for the overriding one, I posted it as https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/289924/108337 for the time being, mutual-linked it with the initial question with comments and tried to have that question reopened on these grounds. This didn't work (with no feedback to guess why).

So, I have two questions:

1. What to do with the answer?

   - Adapt it for the for the much more general overriding question?

     - This will make it a few (if not several) pages long: the general question asks for many licenses at once and implies all similar ones as well, it will take a lot of text to cover them all in the same level of detail
     - Moreover, since more licenses are implied, the scope to cover is unclear and potentially unlimited
   - Reopen the initial question and move it there?
   - Something else?
2. Is the overriding question's scope appropriate?

   - It can be (and is) answered in the "more or less educated guess" way, but
   - Cannot be practically given an answer based on facts rather than opinions